# page won't extend to full height - thin black line showing below footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, height, containers

I'm building a Wordpress website by customizing and editing an existing theme called 'onetone'. It's an one-pager theme. The problem I'm having is that neither the homepage (the one-pager landing page) nor the individual posts/pages will extend to full height.

**Under the footer, there's a thin black line 23 pixels in height, that extends 100% of the width.**

Here's the quirky thing: while I'm logged into the site as an admin, the line disappears. When I'm visiting as an unlogged, regular user the line is there. All major browsers (FF, Opera, IE, Chrome). Also, on my sister's computer with FF installed the line didn't show even when unlogged.

I've searched StackOverflow, and the usual answer to have `<body>` and `<html>` set to `height:100%;` (including `min-height:100%;`) isn't working. I've also added height/min-height to containers and wrappers to test the setting. (Not all, though, only the ones I thought were relevant to the issue I was trying to solve) I've also tried the `margin: 0;` & `padding: 0;`, but NOTHING works.

I suspected it's the footer's fault, but using the *inspect element* function in my browser (and some further tests) I found the footer has nothing to do with it.

In the original, untouched theme, the line doesn't appear. So it must be some of my edits causing it, though even by comparing the original and my edited CSS file line by line, I couldn't find something that should've caused this error. And the CSS is the only thing I've edited.

I'm not a coding expert, and I've about exhausted my wits and available knowledge trying to figure this out. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this glitch?

This is [my site](http://firstinkstudios.com/). The glitch is best seen on posts / pages. If any specific code samples are needed, just say and I'll post them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has this weird image just before the `<body>` tag ends, after all javascript calls:

```
<img src="http://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?v=ext&amp;j=1%3A3.4.1&amp;blog=50532064&amp;post=651&amp;tz=1&amp;host=firstinkstudios.com&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Ffirstinkstudios.com%2F&amp;rand=0.7281985701993108" id="wpstats">
```

Remove it and you're golden

Comment: Thanks so much! It turned out that the weird image is actually part of the official Wordpress Jetpack plugin, more specifically a script that is used for site stats analysis. I didn't even know it existed until now. I searched the plugin options, and disabled it. Now the black line is gone.

Comment: Yea you got it. Some plugins have those kinds of things, and its all fun and games until you have some weird problem like that. Glad I could sort it out for you

Answer (score 1):

There's a background color on body. Getting rid of that fixes the "border".

```
body.custom-background {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Also there's a smiley on the bottom

It looks like this

```
<img src="http://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?v=ext&amp;j=1%3A3.4.1&amp;blog=50532064&amp;post=444&amp;tz=1&amp;host=firstinkstudios.com&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Ffirstinkstudios.com%2Fblog%2F&amp;rand=0.1907386933453381" id="wpstats" scale="0">
```

Comment: +1 for finding the same image I did, but the background has no influence, I think. I tried only removing that funky smiley and it worked fine!

Comment: It was actually the little smiley causing the problem. It was part of the Jetpack Wordpress plugin, specifically th part of it monitoring the site page visit stats. It didn't show while logged is an admin because the plugin didn't monitor visits by admins. I wasn't even aware the thing existed until now, fortunately there was an option within the plugin to hide it, and with it disappeared the black line, too.

Comment: @V_Shaft OT: Yeah, it's a common technique to track visitors with JavaScript disabled using images. Image gets loaded -> user is tracked. You can hide the image using CSS.